# Playing with my sister on mc pc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have a Minecraft account and I added a user so I have two users on my account. Can we play on the same realm or server at the same time??

Comment: On different PC 's? Or do you want splitscreen?

Comment: If by "added a user" you mean you [added a profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRASN.png), no.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't play at the same time on your realm with the same account. 
You can either buy another account for her or both of you play offline on a LAN server.

Answer (score 0):

Profiles have nothing to do with the account itself, they are for quickly and easily changing your client and/or minecraft options. So no.